# How to get list of all named ranges saved in one google sheet with script?

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with several named ranges. All ranges created with usual tools from context menu selected area.
So my question how can I get a list of these named ranges with a script to use like data validation rules?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this ......[Spreadsheet.getNamedRanges()[i].getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#getName())

```
function allMyNamedRanges() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgA=ss.getNamedRanges();
  let names=[];
  rgA.forEach(function(rg,i){names.push([rg.getName()]);});
  sh.clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,names.length,1).setValues(names);
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm not sure why you would want to get back a 2D array. Was it for the data validation rules? I ended up putting it in regular 1D array for my use.

Comment: I wanted to be able to post them to a spreadsheet with setValues()